# regex to select only first instance of string (no duplicates)

Tags: regex

I am using this regex

```
(rs)\w+/
```

to select strings that begin with the string 'rs', i.e.

*..the biomarker **rs4343** but not **rs4342**. However **rs4343** ..*

this returns: rs4343, rs4242, re4343

Is it possible to use regex to select only the first instance of a matched string to avoid duplication, i.e. to return: rs4343, rs4242

I can use JS or PHP regex.

Comment: collect them in array and then remove duplicates

Comment: Use the right tool for the job. There are more tools than just regular expressions.

Comment: @ Jack, yes I know - but I would like to know if it can be done using regex alone

Comment: and as per the accepted answer it can..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(rs\w+)(?!.*\1)
```

#### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UXUro8/1)

Details:

- `(rs\w+)` - Group the required match
- `(?!.*\1)` - Use negative lookahead to assert that there is no same match after this

Comment: Only one remark - it matches the last occurrence, but since it is the same as previous instances that does not make any difference. Also, you should take care of the dot behavior if you have matches spanned across multiple lines. Also, with very large inputs, the regex might cause performance issues (`.*` inside the pattern involves some backtracking). It is really better to just collect matches and remove dupes with the language means.